# Loss in quality on downsized sprites in Game Maker

Tags: sprites, game-maker

I'm having an issue with sprites quality in Game Maker.

I have some sprites used for UI with an original size of 2048*512. I need to resize them in game to 512*128. But when I do, I got a loss in quality.

This is the original picture, resized to 512*128 with a third-party software:

[image]

This is the sprite, as it appears in Game Maker room editor (and in game) once resized to 512*128:

[image]

Are there general guidelines for this kind of situation?

By the way, it's on Windows. Though I tried launching the game on an Android device and the result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try activating **Interpolate colors between pixels** in Global Game Settings->Windows->Graphics
[image: ICBP]

Comment: I got the same result, with or without the option. It was actually already checked and I tried unchecking it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this very unpleasant problem, which is related only to the way you make GM:S draw things. The solution I found is very simple, instead of drawing directly to the screen, I first draw whatever I need onto a [surface](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/surfaces/), then I draw the surface itself on the screen. The interpolation quality is way better than drawing onto the screen, both for sprites and fonts (since fonts are stored in texture groups as well as sprites).

Comment: I wonder if Game Maker enables mipmapping on Surfaces, but not on other textures/sprites (implicitly assuming that you'll only be displaying those at native size or larger, not smaller)

Comment: That's a tricky question, I don't guess so since you can preview texture pages, and there aren't smaller versions of bigger sprites. You may want to implement your own mipmapping algorithm if you need one.